# Определение корня слова "леечка"

Tags: словообразование

Какой корень в слове "леечка"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корень: "ле-", суффиксы: "е-, ч-, к-", окончание: "-а".

Answer (score 2):

наверное, все-таки корень лей-, суффикс -эч и суффикс -к.

Answer (score 0):

Корень леу, суффикс -ечк. Двойное Й упростилось вонетически.

Comment: @behemothus, Вы, конечно, человек творческий. Но все же следите за своей орфографией. "вонетически" - это уж как-то, знаете ли, ... вонетически ;-)  
Так все же -леу- или -лей-?